# Multiple objects Rotated in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rotation

I would like to create a snowman in OpenGL 2.0.  I would like to rotate the entire shape, but every time I run the program it doesn't work.

```
    glPushMatrix();

    //bottom sphere
    glTranslated(tranX,tranY-2,tranZ);
    glRotated(rotX,1,0,0);
    glRotated(rotY,0,1,0);
    glRotated(rotZ,0,0,1);
    glScaled(scaX,scaY,scaZ);

    glColor3f(1.1,.7,.99);
    glutSolidSphere(1.5,30,30);

    //middle sphere
    glTranslated(tranX,tranY+2.3,tranZ+8);
   glRotated(rotX,1,0,0);
    glRotated(rotY,0,1,0);
    glRotated(rotZ,0,0,1);
    glScaled(scaX,scaY,scaZ);

    glColor3f(1.1,.7,.99);
    glutSolidSphere(1.3,30,30);

    //top sphere
    glTranslated(tranX,tranY+2,tranZ+10);
    glRotated(rotX,1,0,0);
    glRotated(rotY,0,1,0);
    glRotated(rotZ,0,0,1);
    glScaled(scaX,scaY,scaZ);

    glColor3f(1.1,.7,.99);
    glutSolidSphere(1,30,30);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'doesn't work'?

Comment: The answer is already given, but I wanted to add a recommendation: You could try to avoid the old fixed-function pipeline and use glm (http://glm.g-truc.net/) to build your own little scene graph engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to know about OpenGL transformations is that they modify the current coordinate system, and not individual objects.  For example, when you call `glRotated`, it rotates the coordinate system the provided angle around the axis supplied, and affects every bit of geometry you render after calling it, until you change or replace the matrix (by calling `glPopMatrix`, `glLoadMatrix`, etc.).

In your example, you rotate each sphere of the snowman, but don't have an overarching rotation that affects all of the objects in the scene.  Try placing the rotation(s) that you want to affect the entire scene immediately after the `glPushMatrix` call at the top of your routine.